# How to initialize a list within a list collection

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I have a class called `Item` which is holding a `Airpricepoint` list. I am able to create and intialize all the properties of the class and add `Airpricepoint` list. In `Airpricepoint` class i have another list `AirPricingInfo`  which are having few properties. How do I access the members of `AirPricingInfo`, initialize them and add to the list?

```
public class Item
{
    public List<Airpricepoint> AirPricePoint { get; set; }
}

public class Airpricepoint
{
    public  List<Airpricinginfo> AirPricingInfo { get; set; }
    public string AirPricingResultMessage { get; set; }
    public string FeeInfo { get; set; }
    public string FareNote { get; set; }
    public string TaxInfo { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string TotalPrice { get; set; }
    public string BasePrice { get; set; }
    public string ApproximateTotalPrice { get; set; }
    public string ApproximateBasePrice { get; set; }
    public string EquivalentBasePrice { get; set; }
    public string Taxes { get; set; }
    public string Fees { get; set; }
    public string Services { get; set; }
    public string ApproximateTaxes { get; set; }
    public string ApproximateFees { get; set; }
    public string CompleteItinerary { get; set; }
}

public class Airpricinginfo
{
    public object FareInfo { get; set; }
    public object FareStatus { get; set; }
    public IList<FareInfoRef> FareInfoRef { get; set; }
    public object BookingInfo { get; set; }
    public IList<TaxInfo> TaxInfo { get; set; }
    public string FareCalc { get; set; }
}

var lowfaresearchres = new Lowfaresearchres();
lowfaresearchres.Items= new Item();
lowfaresearchres.Items.AirPricePoint = new List<Airpricepoint>();    
lowfaresearchres.Items.AirPricePoint.Add(new Airpricepoint()
    {
        ApproximateBasePrice = airPricePoint.ApproximateBasePrice,
        ApproximateTotalPrice = airPricePoint.ApproximateTotalPrice,
        ApproximateTaxes = airPricePoint.ApproximateTaxes,
        ApproximateFees = airPricePoint.Fees,
        BasePrice = airPricePoint.BasePrice,
        Taxes = airPricePoint.Taxes,
        TotalPrice = airPricePoint.TotalPrice
    });
```

Comment: Do you know how to access an item in a list? If not, look up some C# tutorials about the fundamental/basic collections in C# / .NET...

Comment: You could also have the `Item` constructor take care of instantiating the `List<Airpricepoint>` for you so you can just add from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you're asking is two parts - how to initialize a list with items (without calling `Add`), and how to initialize a list that contains other lists (which is actually the same answer).

The syntax to initialize any object inline is to use curley braces `{}` after `new ObjectType` and inside the braces you have a comma-separated list of `PropertyName = Value` pairs.

A simple form of this using a class with single properties would be:

```
var person = new Person { Name = "Henry", Age = 25 };
```

A simple form of this using a single list is:

```
var stringList = new List<string> { "one", "two", "three" };

var people = new List<Person>
{
    new Person {Birthday = DateTime.Now, Name = "Jack"},
    new Person {Birthday = DateTime.Parse("1/1/1980"), Name = "Jane"}
};
```

With a nested list, it would look something like:

```
var listOfListOfStrings = new List<List<string>>
{
    new List<string>{ "one", "two", "three" },
    new List<string>{ "four", "five", "six" }
};
```

For populating your objects, you can do it a few ways. One is to create and initialize the inner most lists first, then add them to the parents as you create them:

```
// Create child lists
IList<FareInfoRef> fareInfoRef = IList<FareInfoRef>(); // And add some items
IList<TaxInfo> taxInfo  = new IList<TaxInfo>(); // And add some items

// Create the parent and add children
Airpricinginfo airPricingInfo = new Airpricinginfo 
{
    TaxInfo = taxInfo,
    FareInfoRef = fareInfoRef,
    // initialize other properties
}

// Continue with this pattern. . .
```

But what I think you're asking is, how can you do it all inline (which might look a little messy but may be more concise).

So applying this concept to your objects, you would have something that looks similar to this (note I did not compile this, so there may be a minor error somewhere):

```
lowfaresearchres.Items.AirPricePoint = new List<Airpricepoint>
{ 
    new Airpricepoint
    {
        AirPricingInfo = new List<Airpricinginfo>
        {
            new Airpricinginfo
            {
                TaxInfo = new IList<TaxInfo>(),
                FareInfoRef = IList<FareInfoRef>()

                // Add other AirPricingInfo properties
            }, 
            // Add more Airpricinginfo objects separated by commas
        }

        // Add other Airpricepoint properties
    },
    // Add more Airpricepoint objects separated by commas
};
```